# How to calculate Temperature Humidity Wind Index?

Tags: temperature, atmospheric-science, weather, humidity, meteorology

I would like to know how to calculate Temperature Humidity Wind Index (THW Index)? I know how to [calculate Heat Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index) and [Wind Chill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chill). I am asking this because my weather station [Davis Vantage Pro2](http://www.davisnet.com/weather/products/weather_product.asp?pnum=06152) calculates THW index but I could not find any information on [NOAA](http://www.noaa.gov/). This is what it says under Help for my weather station:

> The THW Index uses humidity, temperature and wind to calculate an apparent temperature that incorporates the cooling effects of wind on our perception of temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_12028315_calculate-thw-index.html) has an explanation for how to calculate the THW index.

The Heat Index formula is complicated enough I don't want to try doing it in markup; but the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_index#Formula) you linked has that formula.  From there THW is simple enough.

THW = HI - (1.072 * W)

Note that the formulas require a temperature in Degrees Fahrenheit and a wind speed in miles per hour.