# Temperature-Humidity-Wind (THW) index for hot and cold weather

Tags: temperature, atmospheric-science, weather, humidity, meteorology

Does anyone know the formula (or the algorithm, even a fortran code) to calculate the Temperature-Humidity-Wind (THW) index not from the heat index but in general? (someone published a (too simple?) formula from the heat index, but that's only valid for high temperatures, not for winter).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32857/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic In fact it is not a duplicate. The reference you provide is only good for summer, when we use the heat index. But for the present season it is completely useless since we are under 21°C. So if someone knows a general formula for the THW index... or at least for temperatures under 21°C, that would be greately appreciated.